# What is exactly Geotrigger service by ESRI?

Tags: esri-geotrigger-service

I am going through the [FAQ's](https://developers.arcgis.com/geotrigger-service/guide/faq/#what-does-the-geotrigger-service-do) of ESRI latest Geo-trigger service & according to FAQ it provides location-based alerts for mobile platform.

What is exactly Geotrigger service by ESRI ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of information about the Esri Geotrigger Service in and linked to by the blog entitled [Introducing Esri’s Geotrigger Service: Welcome to the Future of Geofencing](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2014/02/19/introducing-esris-geotrigger-service-welcome-to-the-future-of-geofencing/) of which the **[FAQs](https://developers.arcgis.com/geotrigger-service/guide/faq/)** are just a small part.

If that does not answer your questions I recommend that you ask a more specific Question.